# Is there a row limit when using a SQLite's INSERT INTO with SELECT query?

Tags: sqlite, insert, bulkinsert

I'm attaching a database (B) to another database (A) and trying to populate an empty table in A by doing something like:

> INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM B.table

[SQLite's documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) mentions this, but it doesn't mention any limit on the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement (or processable by an INSERT statement in this particular scenario).

Is there any limit on this number of rows, or can I assume that all rows returned by the SELECT query will indeed be inserted?
(please note that I'm not looking for alternative ways of copying the data, I really just want to know whether or not I may bump into any unexpected limits here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no limit, excluding the general limits for SQLite, that can be seen in this page: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html , for instance:

> The theoretical maximum number of rows in a table is 2^64 (18446744073709551616 or about 1.8e+19). This limit is unreachable since the maximum database size of 140 terabytes will be reached first. A 140 terabytes database can hold no more than approximately 1e+13 rows, and then only if there are no indices and if each row contains very little data.

And since you are getting rows from a SQLite table, there is no practical limit.